# Which episodes deal with the "Dark" jumper in Quantum Leap?

Tags: episode-identification, quantum-leap

I vaguely recall a series of episodes (perhaps not all consecutive?) in *Quantum Leap* that dealt with a "dark" (i.e. bad, evil) equivalent to Sam.

Which episodes of which seasons did this dark jumper appear in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They were more commonly referred as the Evil Leapers, and they appeared in 3 episodes in the fifth season : "Deliver Us From Evil", "Return Of The Evil Leaper" and "Revenge Of The Evil Leaper". The first 2 episodes featured Alia as the leaper and Zoey as the hologram; in the third, Zoey is the leaper.

Comment: No fair. Batroc has a trademark on "Leaper".

Comment: @Omegacron: if Batroc ever gets his hands on an Ant-Man suit then we could be faced with Batroc the *Quantum* Leaper.

Comment: To add a little color, Alia appears to be in the role as "evil leaper" involuntarily and desperately wants out of the business, while Zoey relishes her roles as observer and then leaper, and Thames *really* loves being the observer for Zoey.